# How to track with Google Analytics the redirects coming from an Android App?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

I have an app that in certain point the user is redirected to Chrome. It's not in-app, but on Chrome itself.

How can I track users that came from the app?

By the way: I don't have access to App code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify the app you can do it append `UTMs` or other parameter in `querystring` to the URL, however if you cannot modify the app there is no way to distinguish these interactions which will be considered `Direct` traffic in Google Analytics.

What you can try to do, but probably it might not be an optimal solution from other points of view, is to create a second page that is the same but with a different URL, insert this page into the site navigation by removing the previous one (still leaving it accessible). In this way the 'ghost' page (current page) you know that you can only access it from the app, while those who surf the web will access the new page.